# Pandas filter rows based on separate dataframe row values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two column-wise identical dataframes `ocrmatches` and `fpmatches`

`ocrmatches.shape` output:

```
(30325, 7)
```

`fpmatches.shape` output:

```
(10268, 7)
```

`ocrmatches.dtypes` output:

```
match_id                      int64
case_id                       int64
match_status                 object
last_updated_date    datetime64[ns]
entity_id                     int64
entity_score                float64
entity_version                int64
dtype: object
```

`fpmatches.dtypes` output:

```
match_id                      int64
case_id                       int64
match_status                 object
last_updated_date    datetime64[ns]
entity_id                     int64
entity_score                float64
entity_version                int64
dtype: object
```

`case_id` is a base value for my analysis. `case_id` can have multiple `match_id` assigned and `match_id` can have one or more `entity_id` assigned while `entity_id` can have one `entity_version`, but `entity_version` may vary. `entity_version` is an int that contains first 8 digits for the date in `YYYYMMDD`format and either 14 or 16 digits for the version itself - the higher the number, the newer the version. `entity_version` may have coincidental duplicate values for different `entity_id`.
I'm trying to check if:

- `fpmatches` df contains `case_id` values that are present in `ocrmatches` df,
- if yes, does that `case_id` have at least those `entity_id` values (could be others as well, but not relevant) assigned to it,
- if yes, does that `entity_id` has the same or newer `entity_version` assigned

If `case_id` in `ocrmatches` df has correspondent value in `fpmatches` and that value meets all the above conditions, I can mark that `case_id` in `ocrmatches` as `True` (in a separate column, e.g.).

csv files for the mentioned dataframes can be found [here](https://github.com/punkuotukas/drafts).

I got as far as using `pd.groupby(ocrmatches['case_id'])`, but other than that - utterly stuck.
Any ideas on how to proceed would be very much appreciated.